# android MotionEvent for on finish touching

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview with image about it, i want while the using is touching the textview the image will change and when the using finish touching the image will become to the old image, i tried like this

```
tv_addToBasket.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    tv_addToBasket.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.favorite, 0, 0);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

but i didn't know what is the `MotionEven` for leaving the touch i mean when the using finish touching

Comment: Have you tried using state list drawable ? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList
edit - to answer the touch even question, when the user stops touching you will get a MotionEvent.ACTION_UP event. (remember to use the motion event mask when comparing these)

Comment: this site is not allowed here

Comment: i prefer if there is a MotionEven, it is easier

Comment: @SagiAntebi please give my you solution as answer

Comment: what is event mask ? how to compare them? i am using `==` is it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see if the following solves your problem (from memory, haven't tried to compile this code) -

```
if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
//down
}
else if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
//up
}
```

You can also use event.getActionMasked() from certain API levels.

Comment: again still the same, just when i touch the textview the image change, but when i leave the touch it didn't comes back

Comment: It is most likely because the view consumed the touch event. what happens when you return true in your custom ontouch ?

Comment: you are Enshtine of android, when i return true, it works thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaak